# How to set NavItem active for anchor tag with Gatsby and Reactstrap?

Tags: gatsby, reactstrap

I have a navbar menu with a couple of menu items in it within a Gatsby site that is using Reactstrap. The menu items are set to point to anchor tags within that page (e.g. `#anchor1`).

```
<Nav navbar>
    <NavItem>
        <Link to="#anchor1" activeClassName="active" className="nav-link">Anchor 1</Link>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem>
        <Link to="#anchor2" activeClassName="active" className="nav-link">Anchor 2</Link>
    </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Whilst the links work perfectly well, the menu items do not appear as active: the `active` class is not added to the `NavItem`.  How do I get the menu items to be highlighted when the user navigates to them?

Answer (score 0):

From [Gatsby Link documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation):

> **Neither `<Link>` nor navigate can be used for in-route navigation with a
>   hash or query parameter**. If you need this behavior, you should either
>   use an anchor tag or import the `@reach/router` package—which Gatsby
>   already depends upon—to make use of its navigate function

Due to this incompatibility, I guess your error comes from there.

However, you can try using a `state` when clicking the link and use this state to set a class name:

```
<Link
  to={`/photos/${id}`}
  state={{ fromFeed: true }}
>
```

The last solution, that will work for sure is to use a regular `<a>` with your hash as the documentation points.